When testing a vyper contract in moccasin/titanoboa, how do you expect a revert?
def test_revert():
    # I expect this to revert
    my_contract.func()


Use with boa.reverts
import boa

def test_revert():
    with boa.reverts("my revert error"):
        my_contract.func()

